# resizebox applied on itemize

Tags: graphics

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

%\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{itemize}
  \item First Item
  \item Second Item
\end{itemize}
%}
\end{document}
```

If I remove the comments, I have only one line with texts in both items in it. How can I fix it?

**Update**: The actual usefulness may show up in beamer. The following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
%\resizebox{\linewidth}{0.8\paperheight}{
\begin{itemize}
  \item First Item
  \item Second Item
\end{itemize}
%}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I expect to use this method to make full use of the space (i.e. fonts size automatically shrinks or increases). However, it gives me a compilation error after uncommenting the two lines:

```
./test.tex:14: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.14 \end{frame}

? 
./test.tex:14: Emergency stop.
 ...                                              

l.14 \end{frame}
```

How would I fix it?

Comment: The idea here would be to set the `itemize` in a box - a `minipage` - of fixed width. However, that would defeat the purpose, as then you wouldn't need to resize it to `\linewidth`. I wonder whether it would be more appropriate to show the actual use-case (perhaps highlighting an [XY problem](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2449/5764)).

Comment: @Werner Thanks for the comments---I've updated the question.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest here is to use `\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}`...`\end{varwidth}` (from the [`varwidth` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth))... but I'm afraid it won't yield optimal results in general...

Comment: @werner I think to make it simple, what I meant is to seek a way to limit the height. If the height is too large, then decrease the font size. Do you happen to know a way to do it? Thanks

Comment: Related [Problem resizing an itemize environment with a \scalebox: “Something's wrong”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284922/resizebox-applied-on-itemize) .